# Count number of dictionaries in list satistying condition on value

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I get the number of dictionaries where value satisfies a given condition?

```
list_of_dict = [
                   {'seq_no': 10, 'file_path': 'file/path', 'rel_item': None},
                   {'seq_no': 22, 'file_path': 'file/path', 'rel_item': 0},
                   {'seq_no': 32, 'file_path': 'file/path', 'rel_item': 0},
                   {'seq_no': 90, 'file_path': 'file/path', 'rel_item': 0},
                   {'seq_no': 10, 'file_path': 'file/path', 'rel_item': None},
 ]
```

I would like to count the number of dictionaries where key `rel_item=None`.

Comment: Do you accept pandas method ?

Comment: Please suggest simple python without importing from other modules!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Yes, I might tried some code, I am learning to code. Thanks for advice @MooingRawr.

Comment: My point is, show your effort you've tried, even if it doesn't work we can tell you why it doesn't work and how to fix it. Thus you learn more from it.

Comment: @jpp ticked the one I tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
c = sum(i['rel_item'] is None for i in list_of_dict)
# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
len([x for x in list_of_dict if x["rel_item"] == None])
```

Comment: Kind of a waste to generate a new list just to find the len of it, don't you think ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) the `list_of_dict` based on your criteria

```
>>> len(list(filter(lambda x: x['rel_item'] is None, list_of_dict)))
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `map` then

```
sum((map(lambda x : x['rel_item'] is None,list_of_dict)))
Out[721]: 2
```

Comment: Kind of a waste to generate a new list with map on top of it just to find the len of it, don't you think ?

Comment: @MooingRawr then we remove the list here